# RegExp вырезать определенные JS-скрипты

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Генерируются два HTML-результативных файла, в которых есть пачка JS-скриптов, которые перед выводом нужно частично убрать, при этом содержимое некоторых из них имеют перенос строк.

Сделал два наброска, подскажите пжл, как вырезать только те скрипты, которые под комментарием "ниже стоящий скрипт вырезать", не затронув другие:

https://regex101.com/r/PLvINJ/1

https://regex101.com/r/Pus9JP/2

Comment: нужно искать вместе с комментарием: https://regex101.com/r/oB6TMt/1

Comment: нет, без комментария, только от <script> до </script> включительно. Комментариев в раб. версии не будет

Comment: тогда в принципе задача невозможная, если ты не знаешь какой именно скрипт тебе надо удалить.

Comment: В текущем виде непонятно чем первый скрипт с алертом отличается от скрипта, который надо удалить.

Comment: содержимым отличается, именно по содержимому думаю можно как-то определить

Comment: Как ты по содержимому можешь отличить что надо удалять? Если у тебя содержание скрипта одно и то же всегда - то используй обычную замену, даже регулярное выражение не нужно

Comment: Используйте `/<script(?:\s[^>]*)?>\s*\(function([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/g` - https://regex101.com/r/PLvINJ/2

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - спасибо!

Comment: @Александр, обрати внимание, что если у тебя будет свой скрипт с самовызывающейся функцией - он тоже удалится

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном случае вы можете воспользоваться тем, что сразу после начального тега `<script...>` в строке присутствует ноль и более пробельных символов и текст `(function`:

```js
/<script(?:\s[^>]*)?>\s*\(function([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/g
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/PLvINJ/2).

**Подробности**

- `<script`  - текст `<script`
- `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - опциональная незахватывающая подмаска: пробельный символ и ноль и более символов, отличных от `>`
- `>` - символ `>`
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `\(function` - текст `(function`
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: ноль и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `<\/script>` - текст `</script>`